# Entity Framework: Get the Name of an EntityType Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I get the Name, of an EntityType object? I see the Full Name which include the Namespace prefix also. I really just want LkAddressType,  Not PropertyManagement.Data.Entities.LkAddressType. Is there a Method() to conduct this?

[image]

Otherwise, I will go with the CLR Type. not sure if that is optimal way.

Comment: hi @TheGeneral .name includes the long namespace, I just need LkAddressType, GetType().Name will result in "EntityType"

Comment: Nah, that wont work either, sorry i misunderstood the type you were working with

Comment: ClrtType.Name is what you need.

Comment: hi @SvyatoslavDanyliv feel free to write with answer then, I heard ClrType is not best method, usually there is a GetMethod, but whatever works,  thanks

Comment: For "user friendly name" you could use [`DisplayName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitytypeextensions.displayname?view=efcore-3.1) method. But not sure what you can do with it, for instance it can't be used as argument to `FindEntityType` since it's not uniquely identifying the entity type.

Comment: hi @IvanStoev DisplayName works perfect, feel free to write in answer, and I can send points, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.GetGetEntityTypes()` returns `IEnumerable<IEntityType>` and `IEntityType` has only one property to get real class type for entity - ClrType.

So, just get `ClrType.Name` and you will have desired class name.

Comment: I posted answer and sent points, feel free to thumbs up question also, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use nameof(entity) or typeof(entity).Name. Both should give you the name of the object if it's what you are looking for.

Ps not enough rep to comment

Edit: typo

Comment: I was trying that and it did not work, 'expression does not have a name'

Answer (score 0):

Use method `DisplayName()` and you will have desired class name, without prefix namespaces, etc.